# using GCC 4.4 library with GCC 4.8 application

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++, libgcc

I am writing an application and I would like to use GCC 4.8 on rhel7. My problem is that I need to use a 3rd party shared lib which was built using GCC 4.4 built on rhel6.

Comment: The fundamental problem is : what happens if you match a `new int` from 4.4.8 with a `delete` from 4.8.5 or vice versa? Using `extern "C"` on the interface is not a magic fix, because `int*` is allowed in C.

Answer (score 1):

> Someone suggested I create an interface between my app
>   and the library using extern "C" to avoid ABI issues of going between c++03
>   to c++11, and only pass simple C structs in the interface.

That's a meaningful suggestion as it's too hard to preserve ABI compatibility in C++ interfaces.

> But they also suggested its possible I might have to copy and link
>   libstdc++ and libgcc from the rhel6 machine since the 3rd party lib
>   (and my interface) is built using those. This is where I am confused.

Both libgcc and libstdc++ preserve backwards compatibility (unless in [GCC5](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/) but that's not your case) so the 3rd party lib should work just fine with RHEL7 libs.

> Given that the major version (libName.so.major.minor.x.z) of libstdc++
>   and libgcc is the same on rhel6 and 7, do I really need to copy them
>   from rhel6 to 7?

No (see above).

> Cant I build my interface on rhel6, and just copy it along
>   with 3rd party lib to rhel7 (without copying old libstdc++/libgcc)?

Yes, this will work.

> I mean, since stuff built using old libstdc++/libgcc
>   should be forward compatiable, no?

Correct (they usually say that "new versions of standard libs are backwards compatible i.e. software compiled with older libs will continue to work").

> Can I run into issues (ABIs)?

If you somehow manage to pass STL object created in one libstdc++ to another you'll have weird errors. But if both your and 3rd party library have pure C interfaces this should not be an issue (as there's no way for STL objects to escape their containing libraries).

> If I do need to copy libstdc++ and libgcc from rhel6,
>   and link new and old versions together -- how do i do that?
>   will there suggestion of statically linking the new versions work?

This would be unnecessary burden.